# flutter how to create an dart:ffi struct reference

Tags: flutter, dart, struct, ffi

I created a struct with `dart:ffi`.

```
import 'dart:ffi';
import 'package:ffi/ffi.dart';

class TestStruct extends Struct{
   external Pointer<Utf8> strText;
   
   @Int32()
   external int nNum;

   @Bool()
   external bool bIsTrue;


   //contstruct
   TestStruct(String str, int number, bool state){
      strText = str as Pointer<Utf8>;
      nNum = number as int;
      bIsTrue = state as bool;
   }
}
```

I want to create a reference of `TestStruct` and use it. So I wrote the code.

```
TestStruct test = TestStruct("Text", 10, true);
```

but this is an error

```
Subclasses of 'Struct' and 'Union' are backed by native memory, and can't be instantiated by a generative constructor.  
Try allocating it via allocation, or load from a 'Pointer'.
```

I tried searching with the api documentation, but I didn't understand. Do you know how to create a struct as a reference?? thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example:

```
class InAddr extends Struct {

  factory InAddr.allocate(int sAddr) =>
      calloc<InAddr>().ref
        ..sAddr = sAddr;
        
  @Uint32()
  external int sAddr;
}
```

You can allocate this with calloc function

```
final Pointer<InAddr> inAddress = calloc<InAddr>();
```

And free the pointer with

```
calloc.free(inAddress);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, factory won't work. You'll get an error when trying to call it.

Answer (score 3):

While I am late to the party, writing a complete example so that it may be helpful for others new to the FFI scene.

If this is the dart representative struct (from C) -

```
import 'dart:ffi';
import 'package:ffi/ffi.dart';

class TestStruct extends Struct{
   
   @Int32()
   external int nNum;

   @Bool()
   external bool bIsTrue;

  // IMPORTANT: DO NOT DEFINE A CONSTRUCTOR since struct/union are natively allocated
   
}
```

You can instantiate from dart using ffi.Pointer like below.

```
// my_native_helper.dart

 final dynamicLibrary = ... ; // load .so/process

 void some_function() {
  final Pointer<TestStruct > inAddress = calloc<TestStruct >();
    inAddress.ref.nNum= 1234;
    inAddress.ref.bIsTrue = false;

    // ffigen generated method replicating C extern function
    // To auto generate this, define the C signature in a header file
    dynamicLibrary.receiveFromDart(inAddress);

    calloc.free(inAddress);
 }
```

The C method will look like below.

```
extern "C" void recieveFromDart(TestStruct* structPtr) {
  cout << structPtr->nNum << "/" << structPtr->bIsTrue << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the doc you can't create instances of Struct classes:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ffi/Struct-class.html

However, you typically would need pointers. So you can come up with something like that:

```
static Pointer<InAddr> allocate(int sAddr) {
    final pointer = calloc<InAddr>();
    pointer.ref.sAddr = sAddr;
    return pointer;
}
```